# Quarkus: Rest client with generic return type

Tags: java, jersey, quarkus

currently I'm working on a REST API, in which I created a REST Client like in https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client.
This is my client interface:

```
@Path("/measurements")
@RegisterRestClient
public interface MeasurementService {

    @POST
    @Path("/{deviceId}/{datapoint}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<DataSet<Float>> getHistory(@PathParam("deviceId") String deviceId, @PathParam("datapoint") String datapoint, MeasurementHistoryRequest body);

}
```

I tested this and it works fine and I get the expected result with a "200 - OK". But I want to make use of the generic of DataSet<> and let the caller define the exact return type.  I tried this:

```
@Path("/measurements")
@RegisterRestClient
public interface MeasurementService {

    @POST
    @Path("/{deviceId}/{datapoint}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public <T> List<DataSet<T>> getHistory(@PathParam("deviceId") String deviceId, @PathParam("datapoint") String datapoint, MeasurementHistoryRequest body, Class<T> type);

}
```

The T is necessary, because the answer can contain integer, float, boolean or string values. The other API answers with "400 - Bad Request". Therefore I think that Quarkus interprets the additional type parameter as another payload.
Is there a way to make the client work with a generic return type? Or do I have to implement my own client for that?

**EDIT:**
I got the actual payload the client creates and sends from wireshark: `"java.lang.Float"`  (with the two ")
Of course the payload should be the MeasurementHistoryRequest object (what works, when there are no generics).
The answer I get is:

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Unexpected token \" in JSON at position 0"
}
```

Comment: Can you provide details of the log or errors from the console?

Comment: I added a bit to the post. There are no more errors atm.